# How would you go about setting a Linear Gradient using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update the following CSS:

```
#timeline-bg {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFC60B 0%, #FFC60B 30%, #130c0e 30%, #130c0e 30%, #130c0e 100%);
}
```

using jQuery, I have tried the following but can't seem to get it to work:

```
$('#timeline-bg').css({background:'linear-gradient(to right, #FFC60B 0%, #FFC60B '+progress_value+'%, #130c0e '+progress_value+'%%, #130c0e '+progress_value+'%%, #130c0e 100%)'});
```

Where `progress_value` is an integer between 0-100.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing this via CSS?

Comment: Couple of double % marks in your code (%%). Is that intentional?

Comment: Not doing it via CSS and I'm doing a calculation based in jQuery to determine the %